# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Graphic Design's [third moderator election](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Cai] [image: Wrzlprmft]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4993597338288128/0).

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations to our new mods! May their reigns be long and productive!

Answer (score 9):

Congrats guys look forward to working with you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations both. GDSE now has two great new moderators to add to the already excellent team. Who knows, maybe I'll win a spot next time there is an election... :-)

Comment: … or you get called up.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations `@Cai ♦` and `@Wrzlprmft ♦` on grabbing the hammer!

**Don't hit us too hard :P**